# Can I import data to Firebase Firestore database using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to find a way to import a JSON file to the firebase Firestore database by using jQuery. I searched the internet but all I got was by using Nodejs. So, is there any way to do that or is it even possible? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`parseJSON()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jquery-parsejson-method/) method of JQuery and write to the Firestore database [via the JS SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9).